# Android why am I having an error inflating a layer-list for a splash screen

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to create a splash screen for my Android app, I am not too familiar with Android. When attempting to run my app the following error appears:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.example/com.Example.example.SplashActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.example:layout/activity_splash: Binary XML file line #2 in com.example.example:layout/activity_splash: Error inflating class layer-list
```

I try researching this online and I have not seen a scenario similar to this.

activity_splash.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <item android:drawable="@color/colorBlack"/>

        <!-- Set the Background Image-->
        <item android:gravity="center" android:width="500dp" android:height="700dp">
            <bitmap
                android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        </item>


</layer-list>
```

I added the following lines in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Any feedback welcomed. I would like to know what am I missing or is there documentation on how to create a splash screen as I was not able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way to do that is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorWhite">
    </item>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@mipmap/miniheart_red" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

in your activity_splash.xml

And add the following style to styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashScreen" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/activity_splash</item>
</style>
```

In the manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Splash" android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

In this case the Splash activity has not an xml layout:

```
package com.something.iloveher.activities

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)

        finish()
    }
}
```

Comment: I attempted to use this method but had more errors appear

Comment: look at this in your layer-list android:src="@drawable/logo" , if logo is a png file , you got to install a plugin called Android Drawable Importer to add correctly the logo to the drawable folder. Once you restart the IDE after installing the plugin , right click on drawable folder and : New -> Batch Drawable Importer and add your logo

Comment: this video https://youtu.be/FOFR6p5SyGw shows how to create a SplashScreen from zero , it's in spanish but just watch and try to see where is your error , this is the continuation https://youtu.be/P00ghDWthhA

Comment: Thanks, I actually speak Spanish lol it was very helpful and good explanation as to what each line was doing